# Extract still picture from moving background

Tags: adobe-photoshop, cs3, background-removal

I have many computer-synthesized GIF pictures which have different backgrounds but the same sprite on foreground. I would like to extract this sprite using Adobe Photoshop CS3 without having to do a laborious task manually pixel-by-pixel.

Could you suggest some techniques to do so?

Answer (score 2):

i would suggest if you import to library the photo to Adobe Flash, this will give you frame by frame the image from which you can select the frame "still image" you want then export iit as JPEG to your computer.
hope this was helpful.